# Is it possible to show the right side of a string first in an overfilled QTableWidgetItem?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qtablewidget

The user is prompted with a file dialog and chooses a full path which is then put inside a QTableWidgetItem cell within a parent QTableWidget. Currently, when there is an overflow of text in the item and what it can display, it will show the left portion first.

If the full path is *C:\Users\JohnDoe\Example_File1.txt* it will show:
**C:\Users\JohnDoe\Ex...**

I want the user to be able to see the right portion (the file basename) first before the overflow cutoff occurs such that it will read:

**...Doe\Example_File1.txt**

I tried implement the following code which changed the alignment but did not appear to work as described above:

```
    obj = self.QTable1 #A 10x3 table
    for x in range(obj.rowCount()):

        item = obj.item(x,2) #Change alignment for 3rd column (Where paths are stored)
        item.setTextAlignment( QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
```

Answer (score 5):

You must [`textElideMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#textElideMode-prop) to Qt.ElideLeft and disable [`wordWrap`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#wordWrap-prop):

```py
self.QTable1.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideLeft)
self.QTable1.setWordWrap(False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, however this does not end up working for my paths column. I actually found an easier method called .setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideLeft) which appears to work for the non-path columns. After looking into it, the elide seems to fail when the string is a path. Somehow it detects the slashes and reverts to Elide Right. I'm not sure how to disable this.